# Luasocket TCP stops listening after \r\n\r\n

Tags: lua, luasocket

Whenever I receive TCP messages using something like this:

```
local socket=require "socket"
local sv=socket.bind("*",1337)
function love.update(dt)
    local s=sv:accept()
    while true do
        local s,e=s:receive()
        print(e or s)
    end
end
```

It works perfectly fine with `\r\n` spaced http headers, but when I try to http POST to it, I get the headers fine but not the data, witch is after and empty line (\r\n\r\n)
it does the same thing when i use this as a client:

```
s.socket_write(h,"test1\r\ntest2\r\n\r\ntest3") -- (not luasocket)
```

I see test1 and test2

I've tried messing around with the setOption function but it didnt work

Is there any way to receive the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expect, but the default "mode" is to read one line and because your string `"test1\r\ntest2\r\n\r\ntest3"` doesn't have a newline in the end, the `receive` call waits for that newline.

Usually, after you read the headers, you already know the length of the content you want to read, so you can then do `s:receive(number_of_bytes_to_read)` (at least this is what I do and it works without any issues).

Comment: Thanks, i already found out how, i had to use s:receive(headers.Content-Length) for when a POST was detected.

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried filling `socket.receive()` pattern argument? [1]

Not sure which one is default, but You might consider using `socket.receive('*a')` and parsing those new lines later.

[1] http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#receive

Comment: Using *a wont even return test1 or test2 it just returns when the socket closes.