# Error in creating TCP client in lua

Tags: tcp, lua, luasocket

I am trying to create TCP client in lua

```
local host, port = HOST, PORT
local socket = require("socket")
client = socket.tcp();
client:connect(host, port);
client:send("Hello User");
```

this works fine but when i add

```
while true do
    local s, status, partial = client:receive()
    print(s or partial)
    if status == "closed" then break end
end
```

to read data from socket it block total execution of code.

Comment: TO be clear, is it blocking on the receive? Is it doing that even if you kill the connection?

Answer (score 1):

By default, all luasocket I/O operations are blocking. You need to use `socket.settimeout(0)` ([settimeout](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#settimeout)) to disable blocking. You can then check for "timeout" value returned as status and act accordingly.

Depending on how the data is being sent, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837036/luasocket-tcp-stops-listening-after-r-n-r-n/17846232#17846232) may be relevant as well.

Comment: I tried settimeout(0) but by using this request is not blocking but this always return no data.

Comment: Check the link to SO answer I included as you don't seem to add "\n" to your messages and `receive` by default expects a line terminated by newline. Since it doesn't get it, it will return no data (although it may return partial results).